# How would one derive the gravitational potential energy $-GMm/r$?

Tags: forces, newtonian-gravity, potential-energy, differentiation

So we know that the gravitational potential energy between two objects is, $$-GMm/r.$$

How would we derive this? I am curious behind the intuition of this formula.

Comment: Derive it assuming what exactly?

Comment: @Urb I was hoping you could derive using the equation: GMm/R^2. Like I said, I want to know the thought process or the intuition behind this.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potential_energy#Potential_energy_for_gravitational_forces_between_two_bodies

Answer (score 1):

The potential energy is a scalar function $\phi$ so that:

$$-\nabla \phi = -\left(\frac {\partial \phi}{\partial x} , \frac {\partial \phi}{\partial y} , \frac {\partial \phi}{\partial z}\right) = F$$

In the case $\phi = -GMm(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^{-1/2}$

Making the derivatives:

$$F = -\frac{GMm\mathbf r}{r^3}$$

that is the Newton law for gravitation.